# TypeScript LangChain add field to document metadata

Tags: typescript, langchain

How should I add a field to the metadata of Langchain's [Documents](https://js.langchain.com/docs/api/document/classes/Document)?

For example, using the [`CharacterTextSplitter`](https://js.langchain.com/docs/modules/indexes/text_splitters/examples/character) gives a list of Documents:

```
const splitter = new CharacterTextSplitter({
  separator: " ",
  chunkSize: 7,
  chunkOverlap: 3,
});
splitter.createDocuments([text]);
```

A document will have the following structure:

```json
{
  "pageContent": "blablabla",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "my-file.pdf",
    "type": "application/pdf",
    "size": 12012,
    "lastModified": 1688375715518,
    "loc": { "lines": { "from": 1, "to": 3 } }
  }
}
```

And I want to add a field to the metadata

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't currently shown how to do this in the [recommended text splitter documentation](https://js.langchain.com/docs/modules/indexes/text_splitters/examples/recursive_character), but the 2nd argument of createDocuments can take an array of objects whose properties will be assigned into the metadata of every element of the returned documents array.

```
myMetaData = { url: "https://www.google.com" }
const documents = await splitter.createDocuments([text], [myMetaData],
  { chunkHeader, appendChunkOverlapHeader: true });
```

After this, `documents` will contain an array, with each element being an object with `pageContent` and `metaData` properties. Under `metaData`, the properties from `myMetaData` above will also appear. `pageContent` will also have the text of chunkHeader prepended.

```
{
  pageContent: <chunkHeader plus the chunk>,
  metadata: <all properties of myMetaData plus loc (text line numbers of chunk)>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok... just loop over the docs I suppose:

```
for (var _doc of docs) {
  _doc.metadata['doc_id'] = doc_id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `Document` class, with the `splitDocuments` method.

Example:

```
const docOutput = await splitter.splitDocuments([
new Document({pageContent: text}, metadata: {someField: "someValue"})
])
```